# Cauchy sequence of a single rational

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading through my textbook "The Way of Analysis" by Robert Strichartz.

I have a question about the following excerpt:

> "We now believe that we can obtain every real number as the limit of
>   a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers $($**if the number $x$ is rational, then
>   we can take the sequence $\{x, x, x, \ldots\})$** and that every Cauchy sequence of rational numbers has a real number as a limit."

I am a bit confused by the portion in the parenthesis. Can we really get every real number this way? If we take the repeating sequence of $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ $(\text{i.e. } \{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},\ldots\})$ then doesn't this just approach $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}?$ Sure, $\frac{1}{2}$ is also an element of $\mathbb{R},$ but I don't see how we can get numbers like $\pi$ by a Cauchy sequence of the same rational repeating over and over...

Comment: You can't; that's not what he's saying. Presumably he has shown/you already know that every irrational is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rationals. His parenthetical remark shows that every rational, too, is the limit of such a sequence (a constant sequence).

Comment: @BrianO Thanks, this clarifies it

Comment: No, we don't get all real numbers as limits of constant sequences of rationals; we get only the rationals -- which is exactly what it says. You're ignoring the condition **if the number** $x$ **is rational**.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, I understand now

Comment: Of course you can also get any rational  x as a limit of a sequence of other rationals,e.g, x+1,x+1/2,x+1/3,x+1/4,.....